# Problems with background image?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I added a background image to my site the issue is that it pushess the footer way down,

the background image is in the back with a bunch of other div tags but the footer remain in the bottom way in th bottom,  i tried setting a "no-repeat" but if i do that it removes the image, if i set a height it also affects the other div tags/

any idea what might be wrong?

thanks

Comment: Can you post some of your code?

Comment: The `background`-property does not affect the layout of a page. The problem is somewhere else.

Comment: Please post your code or use jsfiddle so we can better understand what you are describing.

Answer (score 0):

Try this (but change the url contents to the path of your background image):

```
<style type="text/css">
    body {
        background-image: url('../images/bg.jpg');
    }
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to know without seeing your code, but it sounds like your footer div is outside of the div which has the background applied to it.

For example:

```
<div id="page_content_with_background_applied">
    ...
</div>
<div id="footer">
    ...
</div>
```

Should probably be something like this.

```
<div id="page_content_with_background_applied">
    ...
    <div id="footer">
        ...
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @Johny:  Cool.  Glad that worked for you.  Welcome to SO.  Please click that little check mark by the answer that worked for you so as to keep answered questions out of the unanswered area.